# Copy attribute information when different element have the same name in XML with python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

So, here's my XML tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
    <query>
        <normalized>
            <n from="Brain_cancer" to="Brain cancer" />
        </normalized>
        <redirects>
            <r from="Brain cancer" to="Brain tumor" 
            />
        </redirects>
        <pages>
            <page pageid="37284" ns="0" title="Brain tumor">
                <revisions>
                    <rev revid="412658600" parentid="412501243" user="Andycjp" userid="55014" timestamp="2011-02-08T03:35:27Z" size="59870" sha1="fe1ff25c27ebc86572aa4be8201cb813e1bf3d32" comment="/* Psychological and behavioral consequences */"  contentformat="text/x-wiki" contentmodel="wikitext" xml:space="preserve">
                    </rev>
                </revisions>
            </page>
        </pages>
    </query>
    <warnings>
        <revisions xml:space="preserve">
        </revisions>
        <result xml:space="preserve">
        </result>
    </warnings>
    <query-continue>
        <revisions rvcontinue="456175380" 
        />
    </query-continue>
</api>
```

So, has you can see, the "revisions" element appears in two differents places, in differents levels. My objective is to reach the attribute "rvcontinue" (who's path is api/query-continue/revisions) to copy it's value in a new variable. It's probably because i'm just not getting it right, but elementTree and xpath didn't work so far.

This is what i've did so far, but it's getting no where

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Brain_tumor_5.xml')

for elem in tree.getiterator():
    if elem.tag=='{http://www.namespace.co.uk}query-continue':
        output = {}
        for elem1 in list(elem):
            if elem1.tag=='{http://www.namespace.co.uk}revisions':
                output['rvcontinue']=elem1.text
        print output

p = tree.find("./api/query-continue/revisions[@rvcontinue=]")
q = p.attrib
print q
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have mostly used lxml, so I don't know what's up with etree, but it appears 
that find from the tree doesn't work, but find from the root does work:

```
>>> tree.getroot().find( 'query-continue/revisions[@rvcontinue]' ).attrib['rvcontinue']
'456175380'
```

Also: I don't know if it's just a typo above, but:

```
p = tree.find("./api/query-continue/revisions[@rvcontinue=]")
```

will give a SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Added Note: It appears that `tree.find( 'api' )` returns None,

but `tree.find( '.' )` returns `<Element 'api' at 0x1004e5f10`>

so `tree.find( './query-continue/revisions[@rvcontinue]' )`

will also work.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question. However, I would use `lxml.etree` (which supposedly provides the same `ElementTree` interface) and the following code:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> doc = lxml.etree.parse('doc.xml')
>>> node = doc.xpath('/api/query-continue/revisions[@rvcontinue]')
>>> node[0].attrib['rvcontinue']
'456175380'
```

Tried with `xml.etree.ElementTree` but doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I copied your XML file to doc.xml... obviously, change to match your environment.